# Android back button forcing app restart and not resuming properly

Tags: java, android, android-activity

In my app my first activity to launch is a login activity (**A**).  When the login is successful another activity is launched (**B**), in doing so activity **A** is killed using `finish()`.  This is to prevent the user being taken back to the login screen if they hit the back button, which works fine.  Now when the app is closed from activity **B** using the home button and restored from the multitasking view the user comes back to activity **B**, which is great.  However, when the user taps the back button in activity **B** the app closes and when the app is restored from the multitasking view, activity **A** is launched again when I actually want the behaviour clicking the home button gives and presenting the user with activity **B**.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You should simply add a check to your login activity, if the user is already signed in finish it and launch your B activity.

Answer (score 0):

I'm really silly, just found my answer in one of the 'related' questions but it didn't come up when I created my question, oh well.

Here's what I did:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK
            && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {
        Log.d("CDA", "onKeyDown Called");
        onBackPressed();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Log.d("CDA", "onBackPressed Called");
    Intent setIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    setIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    setIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(setIntent);
}
```

This essentially emulates what the home button would do in activity **B**.